# ORMLite - add item to the end of the table

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite

I have `CallItem` object and use ORMLite database.  I need to add item to the end of the specified table. I create new item like this:

```
public void saveCallItem(CallItem contact) throws SQLException {
    OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper dbHelper=DatabaseHandler.getInstance(_context);
    dbHelper.getDao(CallItem.class);
    HelperFactory.GetHelper().getCallDao().createIfNotExists(contact);
}
```

But this implementation adds item to the table beginning. I need to the end. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But this implementation adds item to the table beginning. I need to the end. How can I implement this?

SQL database don't guarantee any particular order and are free to reuse previous deleted space in the tables.  ORMLite is just inserting the items into the database and it is SQLite who is making the decision to put it at the beginning.

If you want your items to be returned in a particular order then you should add an order to your queries by using the [`QueryBuilder.orderBy(...)` method](http://ormlite.com/docs/order-by).  You can add a generated-id field and then order by that which should give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, thanks to Gray, I made it like this :

```
Dao<CallItem,Integer> daoSubject = db.getCallDao();
QueryBuilder<CallItem, Integer> qb = daoSubject.queryBuilder();

qb.groupBy(Constants.CALL_DATE);
PreparedQuery<CallItem> pq = qb.prepare();
contactsList = (ArrayList<CallItem>) daoSubject.query(pq);
```

Comment: Just curious.  Why are you doing the (`ArrayList`) cast?

Comment: oh....))) I initialized contactList as ArrayList and this caused the uncompatible types error. Changing its type to List solved the problem )

Comment: It should be `List` unless you really need the `ArrayList` features.